# Unable to pass an array and a variable to server using $.ajax()

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am facing a problem while passing more than one data through $.ajax() to my PHP script.
This is the function I am calling to upload an array of images to a folder through uploadImages.php file and passing two data, form_data and category to the file-

```
function uploadImages(containerId){
container = document.getElementById(containerId);
container.style.display = "none";
var rtnMsg = '';
var success = '0';

var category = form.inpCategory.value;
if(category <= 0) {
        success = '0';
        rtnMsg = 'Please enter value of category.';
        showMsg();  
        category.focus();
        throw new Error(rtnMsg);    
}

var form_data = new FormData();
    var l = document.getElementById('file_to_upload').files.length;
    for (var x = 0; x < l; x++) {
        form_data.append("files[]", document.getElementById('file_to_upload').files[x]);
    }

$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/uploadImages.php', // point to server-side PHP script
    dataType: 'json',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: true,
    data: { form_data: form_data , category: category},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(out){
        // get server response here
        //alert(out);
        // clear file field
        var arrResponse = JSON.parse(out);
        rtnMsg = arrResponse.rtnMsg;
        success = arrResponse.success;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                rtnMsg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                rtnMsg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                rtnMsg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                rtnMsg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                rtnMsg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                rtnMsg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                rtnMsg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            success = '0';
            showMsg();
        }
}).done(function() {
        $("#file_to_upload").val("");
        showMsg();
});
//Nested function. because in case of error, it is not going in done function.
function showMsg(){

    if(success === '1'){
        container.innerHTML = '<strong>Success! </strong>' + rtnMsg;
        container.classList.remove("alert-danger");
        container.classList.add("alert-success");
    }
    else {
        container.innerHTML = '<strong>Error! </strong>' + rtnMsg;
        container.classList.remove("alert-success");
        container.classList.add("alert-danger");
    }
    container.style.display = "block";

}
}
```

The parameters passed in data are form_data which is an array and category which is a variable.
Everytime I run the code, I get this error-

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (products.php:183)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Comment: `dataType: 'text',` need to be `dataType: 'json',` and what is `anything` there? remove that

Comment: @AlivetoDie `anything` is the end of the comment on the previous line, almost certainly a copying erroror the code wouldn't even run.

Comment: The error suggests that the server is returning HTML, not JSON.

Comment: I tried changing 'text' to 'json' but got this error- Error! Requested JSON parse failed.

Comment: If you use `processData: false`, the `data:` option needs to just contain `form_data`, not an object.

Comment: You also shouldn't quote the variables `form_data` and `category`.

Comment: @Barmar, no that is not the problem. I by mistaken put it on next line here.

Comment: @SachinArtani Isn't that what I said? It was a copying error when you wrote it here.

Comment: Which of the things I mentioned isn't the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I changed the code according to you and got this error-
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
      at e (jquery.min.js:4)
      at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
      at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
      at Function.r.param (jquery.min.js:4)
      at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
      at uploadImages (products.php:171)
      at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (products.php:88)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append `category` to `form_data`, and just send that by itself as the AJAX data, not wrap it in an object.

```js
function uploadImages(containerId) {

  container = document.getElementById(containerId);

  container.style.display = "none";
  var rtnMsg = '';

  var success = '0';

  var category = form.inpCategory.value;
  if (category <= 0) {
    success = '0';
    rtnMsg = 'Please enter value of category.';
    showMsg();
    category.focus();
    throw new Error(rtnMsg);
  }

  var form_data = new FormData();
  var l = document.getElementById('file_to_upload').files.length;
  for (var x = 0; x < l; x++) {
    form_data.append("files[]", document.getElementById('file_to_upload').files[x]);
  }
  form_data.append("category", category);

  $.ajax({
      url: 'includes/uploadImages.php', // point to server-side PHP script
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: form_data,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(arrResponse) {
        rtnMsg = arrResponse.rtnMsg;
        success = arrResponse.success;
      }
    );
  }
```

Also check your server script and make sure it *only* returns JSON. And if you're expecting JSON, use `dataType: 'json'` and then it will be parsed automatically.

Comment: I got you but how can I fetch the category in PHP file then?
I am running a foreach loop in PHP file that fetches all the values of $_FILES["files"].

Comment: It will be in `$_POST['category']`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stringify your data before sending it to the server (if your data is purely JSON).

*Example:*

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(your_json_object);

Refer how to use [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) your data before passing to the server.

But since you're uploading images to your server it will be going as a multi-part request and the response you get is expected to be JSON as per the signature I see in your method. Mostly like I suspect the response contains some non-json characters which is why jquery is complaining

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0*

Can you check the Network tab in your browser to see what exactly you get from the server back as a response ? (Sometimes a 500 error page with HTML tags might be given as response which could possibly explain the Unexpected token error you're seeing)